# interchange front and rear camera

Tags: camera

My rear camera is broken and  temporarily I want to use my front camera as my rear camera. is there any way I could do this. I am rooted. The problem doesn't occur when I use the camera app but rather applications such as Barcode scanner and others which do not have the option to change the camera used. I want applications to recognise my front camera as my rear camera. Is there any to accomplish this